# Bottom navigation bar flickers when swipe to application swiper

Tags: android, flutter

When I swipe up with the navigation bar (android one), the separation between android navigation bar and app's bottom navigation bar flickers.

[Here is a video to illustrate](https://imgur.com/a/aAobC6n)

As we can see, a black "line" is drawn between the 2 bars depending of the app position.

I tried to change the colors of my system UI overlay but the color seems to be provided from elsewhere.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Kanit',
        useMaterial3: true
      ),
      home: const BaseScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class BaseScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BaseScreen({super.key});

  @override
  BaseScreenState createState() => BaseScreenState();
}

class BaseScreenState extends State<BaseScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _updateStatusBar();
    _updatePortraitModeOnly();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.background2,
      // bottomNavigationBar: BottomTabBar(),
      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'BottomTabBar',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: AppColors.content1,
              fontSize: 24,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Set status bar transparent
  void _updateStatusBar() {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
        statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
        systemNavigationBarColor: AppColors.background1,
        systemNavigationBarDividerColor: AppColors.background1,
        systemNavigationBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark));
  }

  /// Set portrait mode only
  void _updatePortraitModeOnly() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
      DeviceOrientation.portraitDown,
    ]);
  }
}
```